# Segmentation fault 11 error, Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift

Having issues with Segmentation fault 11 errors. Error appears as so:

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/AnnotatePhotosVC.swift
    cd /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/wb/9dsv1b5j53n8qbwmbh49qf9m0000gn/T/sources-4ce728 -primary-file "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/AnnotatePhotosVC.swift" -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMPopTip -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireImage -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Branch -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DKVerticalColorPicker -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EDStarRating -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jukebox -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MIBadgeButton -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MZTimerLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mixpanel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PubNub -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QueryKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReachabilitySwift -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SZTextView -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftDate -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TCCopyableLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TTTAttributedLabel -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Fabric/iOS" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseRemoteConfig/Frameworks/frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Intercom/Intercom" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app" -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/Obj-C-bridge.h" -module-cache-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -D DEV -D DEBUG -D TARGET_IOS_SIMULATOR -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/swift-overrides.hmap" -Xcc -iquote -Xcc "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-generated-files.hmap" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-own-target-headers.hmap" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap" -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-project-headers.hmap" -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Firebase/Analytics/Sources" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Crashlytics" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Fabric" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseRemoteConfig" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleIDFASupport" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleIPhoneUtilities" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleTagManager" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Intercom" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources/x86_64" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources" -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app" -emit-module-doc-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC~partial.swiftdoc" -Onone -module-name SA_Dev -emit-module-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC~partial.swiftmodule" -serialize-diagnostics-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.dia" -emit-dependencies-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.d" -emit-reference-dependencies-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.swiftdeps" -o "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.o"

/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Firebase/Analytics/Sources/Firebase.h:1:9: note: while building module 'FirebaseAnalytics' imported from /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Firebase/Analytics/Sources/Firebase.h:1:
#import <FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>
        ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/FirebaseAnalytics.h"
        ^
/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FirebaseAnalytics.h:6:9: note: in file included from /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FirebaseAnalytics.h:6:
#import "FIRApp.h"
        ^
/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRApp.h:71:1: warning: conflicting nullability specifier on return types, 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull'
- (nullable instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/include/objc/./NSObject.h:60:1: note: previous declaration is here
- (instancetype)init
^
0  swift                    0x000000010a827b6d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010a8275b6 SignalHandler(int) + 470
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8cdd752a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000010fd2dac8 _sigtramp + 2197120440
4  swift                    0x00000001084ba865 (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::checkOverrides(swift::TypeChecker&, swift::ValueDecl*) + 5749
5  swift                    0x00000001084aa95e swift::TypeChecker::validateDecl(swift::ValueDecl*, bool) + 3150
6  swift                    0x00000001084c56a5 (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::visitFuncDecl(swift::FuncDecl*) + 4453
7  swift                    0x00000001084af112 (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::visit(swift::Decl*) + 3282
8  swift                    0x00000001084aa2e7 swift::TypeChecker::validateDecl(swift::ValueDecl*, bool) + 1495
9  swift                    0x00000001084aa90a swift::TypeChecker::validateDecl(swift::ValueDecl*, bool) + 3066
10 swift                    0x00000001084d79db swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 7627
11 swift                    0x000000010818caab swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 5643
12 swift                    0x0000000107c3900d performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 2765
13 swift                    0x0000000107c36265 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17029
14 swift                    0x0000000107bf382d main + 8685
15 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff80fae5ad start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/wb/9dsv1b5j53n8qbwmbh49qf9m0000gn/T/sources-4ce728 -primary-file /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/AnnotatePhotosVC.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMPopTip -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireImage -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Branch -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DKVerticalColorPicker -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EDStarRating -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jukebox -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MIBadgeButton -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MZTimerLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mixpanel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PubNub -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QueryKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReachabilitySwift -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SZTextView -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftDate -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TCCopyableLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TTTAttributedLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/FirebaseRemoteConfig/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Intercom/Intercom -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/Obj-C-bridge.h -module-cache-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -D DEV -D DEBUG -D TARGET_IOS_SIMULATOR -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Firebase/Analytics/Sources -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Crashlytics -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Fabric -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseRemoteConfig -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleIDFASupport -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleIPhoneUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleTagManager -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Intercom -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app -emit-module-doc-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name SA_Dev -emit-module-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.swiftdeps -o /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AnnotatePhotosVC.o 
1.  While type-checking getter for frame at <invalid loc>
```

Confused to as what the issue is here. I have copied the contents of `AnnotatePhotosVC.swift` to a separate project to check for errors and there are none. But it also seems that there might be an issue with `Firebase` however my class `AnnotatePhotosVC` doesn't use `Firebase` or reference it. What does this error print out mean and what should I be looking for? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late of an answer, but the issue is that the xcode compiler is crashing. This should 'never happen' =), but the recent versions of xcode and swift3 have been buggy and brittle (xcode 8.x)... I saw a lot of these issues (compiler SEGFAULT) when I moved my old firebase project to swift 3 and latest firebase cocoapods (i.e. 3.7.1+). I wish I could tell you which components are causing the issue, but it's highly dependent on your xcode version. I recommend that you move to the GA release of xcode 8.1 and set up your environment as pure Swift 3 with no legacy swift compilation, then install the latest pods for Firebase and you should be OK! (that worked for me).